# Why is Template Tag "if" not working?

Tags: django, pycharm

I have an item with no note.  The note is a OneToOne Relationship with the item.  Yet Django is still show this comment icon, even though the title (tooltip) says `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>`

Here is what PyCharm says the value is of the note field (looks like a Stack trace):

[image]

Here is my template code:

```
{% if item.note.content %}
    <span class="fa fa-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{ item.note.content }}"></span>
{% endif %}
```

Here is my model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class OrderedItemNote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.OneToOneField(OrderedItem, related_name='note')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'order'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'OrderedItemNote for Item #%d' % self.item.pk
```

Comment: If `item` has not a `note` then `note.content` does not exists, it is missing. Try filtering by `item.note` only, and if you need filter by `note`'s `content` add another `if`

Comment: Right.  So then why is the "if" statement being executed in the template?

Comment: Try printing it -> `{{ item.note.content }}`

Comment: I am, it's right there in the "title" attribute and it says `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>`

Comment: So, it actually has a value, it is not `None`. Check your `Item` object.

Comment: Well, the `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>` is not a normal Django result so that must be the actual value.

Comment: See updated question: Looks like it has a stack trace in it.  I would expect Django to store None in there with the OneToOne relationship.  What is the recommended method for dealing with this inside a template?

Comment: Well It actually should be `None`. I don't see where is `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>` comming from. You could try my first comment I think it should work since `content` belongs to `note`, so, if `note` is `None` at first you don't need eval `content`

Comment: If I try to access it in a view then I get Exceptions thrown, but nothing in the template.

Comment: If you strongly need eval `content` value, you could get `item.note.content` value in the view and send it to template via `context_data`.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I think it will be easiest to just create a custom template tag.

Comment: Is the problem just in PyCharm, or does the code not work when you render the template?

Comment: The problem is that the "if" statement is executing in the statement when it shouldn't be.  The note doesn't exist for this item, but yet it's still attempting to show the variable and then shows `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
{{ if item.note and item.note.content }}
```

OneToOne doesn't mean it always exists.

Comment: I tried this, but it still says `<< MISSING VARIABLE >>`